# How to config "redis-ignite-internal-cache-0" in apache ignite

Tags: ignite

I want to run the demo of "$IGNITE_HOME/examples/redis/redis-example.py". But I feel confused about how to config this cache. Can anybody tell me ?

Answer (score 1):

You should start another node with `redis-ignite-internal-cache-0` cache configured and then run this script. You can find some examples with caches configuration in `examples/src/main/java` and `examples/config` folders. Also take a look at the documentation:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#configuration

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config

**UPD**:

You can edit `ExampleNodeStartup` from `examples` module and run it. The following code will create cache with default configuration:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
    ignite.getOrCreateCache("redis-ignite-internal-cache-0");
}
```

If you want to change cache configuration, you can either configure it in xml config file, or create cache using [Ignite.getOrCreateCache(CacheConfiguration)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#getOrCreateCache(org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration)) method

**UPD 2:**

You can also configure cache in XML and start a node with that configuration. Add the following block to Ignite configuration bean:

```xml
<property name="cacheConfiguration">
    <list>
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="name" value="redis-ignite-internal-cache-0"/>

            <!-- Other configuration properties -->
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Then you should either start a node by calling `Ignition.start("<path-to-config>")` or by running `bin/ignite.sh <path-to-config>` script before running a Redis example.

Comment: I've read the doc. But I still felt confused. If it's a property tag, what's the value of "name" and what's the value of "value". Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Lianshuai I added some clarification to the answer. The code I provided should work for Redis example.

Comment: Thank you. It works with the code. But I still want to know how to configure it in xml config file.